# Mysql Function Return

Tags: mysql

I have a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertRaffleTicket`(IN userId BIGINT, IN raffleId BIGINT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RaffleTicket(UserId, RaffleId)
    SELECT userId, raffleId
    FROM RaffleStatus rs
    WHERE rs.RaffleId = raffleId
    AND rs.SoldOut = 0;
END
```

How can I turn this into a function, that will return a value upon successful Insertion into the table?

I have tried:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `addTicket`(UserId int, RaffleId int) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RaffleTicket(UserId, RaffleId)
    SELECT userId, raffleId
    FROM RaffleStatus rs
    WHERE rs.RaffleId = raffleId
    AND rs.SoldOut = 0;
    return rs.SoldOut;
RETURN 1;
END
```

But it is giving me an Error 1109 Unkown table 'rs' in field list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `InsertRaffleTicket`(
userId BIGINT,
raffleId BIGINT
) RETURNS int
BEGIN

DECLARE retValue int;

select SoldOut into retValue from RaffleStatus where RaffleId = raffleId;

INSERT INTO RaffleTicket(UserId, RaffleId)
SELECT userId, raffleId
FROM RaffleStatus rs
WHERE rs.RaffleId = raffleId
AND rs.SoldOut = 0;

RETURN retValue;

END
```

Comment: I might have updated while you were answering, but I keep getting Error 1054 Unkown column `WbId` when I put your example into my database.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check now, I forgot to change variable name

Comment: That now adds the correct ticket. However it always returns 1. I need it to return the SoldOut value. So I know if SoldOut = 0, it added the ticket, if SoldOut = 1, it did not add the ticket.

Comment: Ive updated the code for the soldout output, please check now

Comment: Error 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function.

I should add, RaffleStatus will return all raffle's that do not have all tickets sold for the raffle.

IE: If RaffleId 1 and RaffleID 2 have 12 tickets in each raffle, and they have only sold 10 each, RaffleStatus will return both.

Comment: I believe I have it figured out. The correct way to set the retValue is:

SELECT SoldOut INTO retValue FROM RaffleStatus WHERE RaffleStatus.RaffleId = raffleId;

Comment: Yeah, thats right, I have changed the answer for future references. Please mark as answer if it helped you.